# The utility and use of ARCore with image recognition

Tags: android, augmented-reality, image-recognition, arcore

If I understand correctly, the ARCore does not yet take image recognition into account. Correct me if I'm wrong but, a priori, each time the sdk is coupled with another framework (eg. vuforia) or a library (eg. opencv). These technologies already make it possible to superimpose information on an image, so I would like to know what functionality (s) is being developed with the ARCore in this kind of project, in what way is it relevant to use this sdk.

For example: the Google's Daydream Labs project - "how to make espresso"
 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz4nLqpmPjs)

When passing in front of certain components of the coffee machine, the device displays different information. There is no plane detection and tracking in this project. So what has been developed with the ARCore?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

`Augmented Images API` is available for ARCore developers since ARCore 1.2 was released.

[Augmented Images](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/) in ARCore lets you build AR apps that can respond to 2D images, such as posters or product packaging, in the user's environment. You provide a set of reference images, and ARCore tracking tells you where those images are physically located in an AR session, once they are detected in the camera view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess here but that "how to make an espresso" project is probably doing object recognition using 3d spatial points.  So in theory a different machine could potentially trigger the same tutorial even though it lacks the parts or are in slightly different locations.

I've been trying all sorts of image recognition plugins in conjunction with ARCore and non seem to really work.  They pretty much fight with ARcore.